# How to set ul elements inline and vertical align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap for my site, but when my navbar is navbar-right links sets inline but glyphicon is fixed top. I need that all elemets are vertical aling in one line. Thanks all

HTML

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >

       <li><a class="nav_links" href="#main">Главная</a></li>

       <li id="navi_images"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span></li>

       <li><a class="nav_links" href="#portfolio">Портфолио</a></li>

       <li id="navi_images"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-scissors"></span></li>

       <li><a class="nav_links" href="#">Контакты</a></li>

       <li id="navi_images"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span></li>

       <li><a class="nav_links" href="#">Отзывы</a></li>

    </ul>  

  </div>
```

I can't have any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the following style on ul element

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
   .nav li {
  display:inline;
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height:35px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >

       <li><a class="nav_links" href="#main">Главная</a></li>

       <li id="navi_images"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span></li>

       <li><a class="nav_links" href="#portfolio">Портфолио</a></li>

       <li id="navi_images"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-scissors"></span></li>

       <li><a class="nav_links" href="#">Контакты</a></li>

       <li id="navi_images"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span></li>

       <li><a class="nav_links" href="#">Отзывы</a></li>

    </ul>  

  </div>
    </div>
```